# Get numbers from a specific INPUT Javascript

Tags: javascript

Well, my problem is I need to obtain the values of a specific chain. The cases are stored inside the variable _INPUT

The first line contains T, the number of test cases. T test cases follow, each in a new line. Each test case contains two space-separated integers denoting A and B.

```
_INPUT = "2\n3 9\n17 24";
```

the way I enter the values was:`cont_sqrt(3,9);`
but my teacher dont want this way.
my function is

```
 `function cont_sqrt(a,b){
positives=0;  
for(x=a;x<=b;x++){
sqrtmath=Math.sqrt(x); 
if(sqrtmath % 1 ==0){
positives++;
}
}
console.log(positives);
}`
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your well-described input? And what have you tried to make it happen?

Comment: what output you want, do you want like this _INPUT = "2391724"
or like this _INPUT[0] = 2 _INPUT[1]=3 ... so on

Comment: Easy enough to parse and create a structure, but what structure do you want?

Comment: I'm trying de "sherlock and squares" from hackerrank , I have done the algorithm, the numbers 3 and 9 put the range but i dont know how to put the values in the function, the only thing I tried (but is not right) is cont_sqrt(3,9); and call the function, but i need to take the values from the INPUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isNumeric()`

```
var input = "2\n3 9\n17 24";
var inputSplit = input.split('');
alert(inputSplit);
var arr = [];

$.each(inputSplit,function(i,val){     
    if ($.isNumeric(val)) {
        arr.push(val);
    }

});
 alert(arr);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/7d7pnfyc/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is going to be consistent structure of your _INPUT string, this is how you can do it.

```
var _i = _INPUT.split('\n');

var T = _i[0]; // gives you 2

for(var i=1;i<_i.length;i++){
    var current = _i[i].split(' ');
    var _A = current[0];//Gives you 3 in first iteration and 17 in 2nd iteration and so on
    var _B = current[1]; //Gives you 9 in first iteration and 24 in 2nd iteration.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial number passed is the number of cases that there will be, you could do:

```
var _INPUT = "2\n3 9\n17 24";
var inputParts = _INPUT.split(/\n/);
var caseAmount = inputParts[0];
var cases = inputParts[1].split(/\s/);
var casesInt = inputParts[2].split(/\s/);
var result = {};
result['size'] = caseAmount;
result['cases'] = [];
for(var index = 0; index < caseAmount; index ++){
    result['cases'][index] = {'case' : cases[index], 'caseInt' : casesInt[index]};
}
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
Object
    cases: Array[2]
        0: Object
            case: "3"
            caseInt: "17"
            __proto__: Object
        1: Object
            case: "9"
            caseInt: "24"
            __proto__: Object
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array[0]
    size: "2"
__proto__: Object
```